# Laravel 5 auth many methods

Tags: authentication, laravel, ldap

Tell me, can someone faced with such a problem. Tell us briefly; I have two drivers are configured for authentication - Eloquent and LDAP.
Tell me, how can I implement user authentication methods, it said on the form. What is important, without the use of third-party drivers ollieread/multiauth?
Thank you.

Comment: Which one do you want to use LDAP or Eloquent? I don't think you should be using both. I have however written a system that uses Eloquent for authentication but for adding and updating new users relies on LDAP. Are you trying to use both for some particular reason?

Comment: Excuse me, now I try to explain the essence of ideas. There is a corporate portal in which users can enter our company, using LDAP. For clients that are not in LDAP is necessary to provide another opportunity given authorization in the application.

Comment: Okay. Why don't you want to use multiauth?

Comment: The fact that the use of multiauth lost the ability to use the native Auth :: guest, Auth :: check and so on. Do not tell me how I can fill this gap in the use of the driver multiauth?
Thank you.

Comment: Why is that a problem? I think if you're trying to implement a multi auth system you should be willing to make some changes as such to accommodate a different approach to authentication. Otherwise, sorry I have no idea how to approach the issue. Wish you all the best.